# CSS Background shorthand

Tags: css

Sorry to ask such a basic question, but in spite of the fact that I am not a professional webdesigner, but I already have some more elaborated personal websites than only show one static picture in one static page, I am completely confused, and I am fed up.
OK, that even if I do not put in the right order of CSS properties, the browser shows what I want, but I would like to know if there is an official order for the background properties.

[W3 School](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background_shorthand.asp) says (It does not give all): background-color background-image background-repeat background-attachment background-position.

[Mozilla Developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) says: background-repeat background-attachement background-position / background-size background-origin background-clip background-image background-color;

[Webfx](https://www.webfx.com/blog/web-design/background-css-shorthand/) says: background-image background-position / background-size background-repeat background-attachment background-origin background-clip background-color;

I give up going to look for the official order, because I am not able to decide myself which is the right official one.

Can you tell me how you know it, and from which website can say the official CSS rules ? Or, is there an official CSS statement that background properties order is not important ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MDN links](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background#specifications) to the [official specifications](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds/#the-background) which [say](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds/#values):

> This specification follows the CSS property definition conventions from [CSS2] using the value definition syntax from [CSS-VALUES-3].

That then links to [this document](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/about.html#property-defs) which describes, in detail, how to read the syntax definitions.

The most relevant part of that is:

> A double bar (`||`) separates two or more options: one or more of them must occur, in any order.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Ok, I found the w3.org official rules on the "official specifications" link in you answer above. So, the answer is:  bg-image bg-position bg-size repeat-style attachment visual-box visual-box background-color. I did not understand clearly the "most relevant part". Does it mean that IF I separate the properties with a double bar, the order is not important ?

Comment: @IgorLaszlo — No. I mean that because **the specification** separates the properties with a double bar that the order is not important.